# Best approach for an optimal score in game

Tags: algorithm

In the Android app store there is a two player game called Box Me which is what we used to play when growing up with pen and paper. Each player takes turns to join adjacent dots vertically or horizontally. The objective is to connect a grid of adjacent dots to form a box, while not allowing your opponent to form a box. In the game we play against a bot. For example, a board of 8x8 dots can form 7x7 boxes, 49. I'm  trying to implement an approach (and would appreciate any help) to a high score(maximum number of boxes). Or is there a way to prove that this is futile against a knowledgeable opponent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are asking a gaming question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm looking for an approach, not code. One way to start would be to make moves to limit the number of boxes formed at a stretch - those usually give away the most points to your opponent. The moment three edges are joined and it's your turn you can make a box, and sometimes several in a row. You would understand if you played the game.

Comment: Consider a greedy approach aimed at giving away the **least** number of points (boxes). In the end stages, you must choose to make a line that either gives away 3,4,4, or 5 boxes. You could give away (3+4), and score (4+5), but is the greedy approach always the best approach? And what could you do in the beginning stages to score more in the end, or give away the least?

Comment: No...don't be greedy. And greediness always loses in this game :P

Answer (score 1):

A few things that you must know if you are starting with game (bot player) programming:

- Basic graph algorithms (BFS, DFS, Top Sort etc)
- Min - Max algorithm
- Alpha Beta Pruning
- Concept of heuristics to approximate (and learn to improve) a solution.

As I guess, you must be knowing basic graph algorithms, and for the use case that you mention here, Min-Max (using heuristics of course), should solve your problem.
Alpha Beta Pruning is (kind of) an advanced concept for improving time complexity after implementation of Min-Max.

There are other important concepts to Game Programming that include machine learning, recording played games and using those results etc. You can learn about them later. :)